# La aparente contradicción entre "inmutarse" e "inmutable"

Tags: etimología, prefijos

Si vemos la definición de "inmutable", encontramos:

1. Que **no** puede ser cambiado o alterado.
   "esperanzas inmutables; todo ese orden dentro del cual tiene que moverse es fijo e inmutable"
2. [persona] Que **no** se inmuta o es propenso a **no** inmutarse por nada.
   "permaneció unos segundos quieto, inmutable, como si aquello no fuera con él"

Mi pregunta es: ¿por qué decimos "inmutarse" y no "mutarse"? O sea, ¿qué ocurrió en la evolución del verbo para que mantenga ese prefijo ilógico?

También me gustaría saber si existe un fenómeno parecido con otras palabras (se me ocurre el caso de "inflamable" que, a pesar del prefijo negativo, indica propensión a la combustión).

Answer (score 4):

Si nos fiamos de [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?inmutar), hay dos palabras homónimas en latín que se escriben igual:

- *immutabilis*, que significa "**no** alterable", donde el prefijo **in-** crea un antónimo.
- *immutabilis*, que significa exactamente lo contrario, "alterable", donde el prefijo **in-** significa "internamente" o "hacia dentro".

La segunda versión de "inmutable" no nos ha quedado, pero sí nos ha quedado "inmutarse" con el significado de "sufrir un cambio interno", donde entiendo que "interno" se refiere a que es un cambio de emociones o sentimientos.

La palabra "inflamable" también parece usar el prefijo **in-** con el significado de "internamente". Otro ejemplo que se me ocurre es "inmigrar".

Comment: Buen hallazgo. Lo curioso es que la lengua haya mantenido un vertiente para el verbo y otra para el adjetivo. Vaya confusión.

Comment: @Gustavson supongo que, por un lado, "mutar" en seres vivos tiene otro significado, y por otro lado, "ininmutable" podría ser una cacofonía. Pero esto son suposiciones: es difícil responder a preguntas del tipo "por qué" en etimología.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, resulta muy curioso (y confuso) ver ese parecido homófono (que suena igual) pero que provienen de raíces distintas: en *in*mutar "in" es un preverbio y no un prefijo negativo, como en el segundo caso. (Una situación muy particular que dudo se pueda encontrar replicada).